# What does it mean to add an "ASMX wrapper" to a Web service?

Tags: web-services, delphi

I found a question here regarding a "[Problem in consuming WCF service (basicHttpBinding) in Delphi Win32 Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090611/problem-in-consuming-wcf-service-basichttpbinding-in-delphi-win32-client)," but I don't understand [the answer about using an ASMX wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090611/problem-in-consuming-wcf-service-basichttpbinding-in-delphi-win32-client/1090623#1090623).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please elaborate? What part did you not understand? What specific problem did you have? What have you tried doing so far, and what failed? Describe the failure. Describe what you hoped would occur. You can press the "edit" link below your question to add more information, and that will allow other people to help you better.

Comment: The edit makes it better, but there's still no real question here. All I can discern is that the OP claims not to understand something. That doesn't make a question. I vote to close.

Comment: So what is your actual question?

Answer (score 0):

That's mean you have to create new project in Visual Studio as asp.net web services(which will consist of asmx files) that calls the WCF service and expose it as standard web services.

After that will be able to import the asxm wrapper by using the WSDL importer in Delphi.