# Calling WCF from Delphi 5

Tags: wcf, delphi, delphi-5

We have a really old application hanging around.  It is on the block to be re-written.  But since it is very complex the rewrite keeps getting put off.

Now I need to know if there is a way to get a Delphi 5 application to call a WCF web service?

I know WCF was not even a glimmer in its inventor's eye when Delphi 5 was released... but can it be done?  If so, how?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090611/ Delphi 5 might be a stretch though.

Answer (score 5):

You can communicate to WCF web services using SOAP over HTTP.  Delphi 5 does support SOAP to some extent, but in my experience its early implementation isn't especially compatible with .NET 2.0 (or higher) WSDL.  You might wish to try importing the WSDL and see what Delphi makes of it - but I wouldn't get your hopes up.

If that doesn't work, underneath it all it's just a bunch of web requests, so it's theoretically possible to do what you're asking using your own marshalling routines (on top of Indy HTTP, for example).  The question is - how easy will it be to marshall your requests + the responses into data structures that you can manipulate in Delphi 5?

An alternative strategy that you might consider would be writing a proxy/wrapper in a suitable language (i.e. something .NET) and expose a more Delphi-5-friendly interface.

Comment: Delphi 5 doesn't support SOAP at all out of the box. WS support was introduced in Delphi 6, but even that is now an outdated implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Delphi 5 doesn't support calling web-services out of the box, as that feature was introduced with Delphi 6.

The Delphi support for web-services got updated around the Delphi 2005/2006 era to be compatible with newer SOAP versions (used for instance in .NET 2.0 and higher).

RemObjects have an alternative implementation for web-services in Delphi (and a lot more communication stuff), but they don't support Delphi 5.

Delphi 5 can perform HTTP requests and use XML, so you could build your own stuff based on that. It'd take at least days, if not weeks to do that in a generic way, but a specific solution that works only for one web-service call could be doable in a shorter time frame.

Answer (score 1):

WCF web services are just web services, right?  Given that your WCF service is using http for transport you should be able to treat it like any other web service.  Really even in regards to whether it's a SOAP, REST or other formatted message passing is meaningless.  If Delphi 5 can call a web service, it *should* be able to call a WCF service.

If you own the web service the story obviously gets even better.

Comment: I own the web service.  But how can Delphi 5 call a web service?

Comment: Not a Delphi coder, but looks like Delphi 5 at least has a good XML parser.  Try http://exposureroom.com/members/skumar/tutorials/post/20